# Serial port testing using the same laptop

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am doing serial port connection between  laptop and a chip . without the details ,I will show you small sample from the code :

this is the code which functioing the port , see the code to give you my question .

```
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort(
               "COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.
        // Open the port for communications
        port.Open();

        // Write a string
        port.Write("Hello World");

        // Write a set of bytes

        // Close the port
        port.Close();
```

\

my question is : how can i test this simple code using my laptop , just my laptop , a loop back way  , is there a way to test this code on my laptop without using cable or a chip ?

note  : my laptop is HP pavilion g6 .
note: the first line of the code which give the port the parity and the stop bit ,this is not my configuration .

Comment: What do you expect to test? You need "something" on the other side to react to your commands, if you don't have anything what is the point of your "test"?

Comment: Yes, simply wire up a female DE-9 (DB-9) connector, and wire pin 2 to 3 (TX to RX). Plug it in. Any bytes you send should be waiting in your receive buffer. @Scott, I'm guessing he wants to test the .NET API for the serial port, making sure he's sending and receiving properly.

Comment: @Steve plz put your answer until others see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop back pretty simply.

Find yourself a female DE-9 (aka DB-9) connector. Wire pins 2 and 3 together, and plug it into your serial port. Whenever you write a byte to the port, it'll loop back into the receive buffer. This won't loop back things like RTS/CTS, etc., but that can also be done with a simple wire.

A quick Google search yielded the following site. I didn't read it, but it looked pretty straightforward: http://www.sealevel.com/support/article/AA-00138/0/How-To-Construct-Serial-Loopback-Adapter-Plugs.html

Answer (score 1):

- Wire the TX pin to the RX pin
- Change your program to write and then read

Comment: No reason for 2 ports or a null modem cable. Just wire the TX pin to the RX pin and you'll receive the same bytes you send.

Answer (score 0):

to watch the traffic you can install one of the available sniffers.
if your system has no registered com devices. you can install either a com port simulator or install a USB driver for a com port.